# portforward with UPnP

Tags: c++, windows, upnp, portforwarding

I am writing a networking application and need to forward a port on a router if UPnP is enabled. Where can I find C++ code for forwarding a port with UPnP? The the code must work on windows xp, windows vista, and windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides various [UPnP APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382303.aspx).